# TabBarController: always jump to root NavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following hierarchy in my app:

- there is a `TabBarController` (X)
- each of its items points to a `NavigationController` (A, B, C...)
- each of those `NavigationController`s starts a hierarchy (e.g. A1, A2, A3,...) of `TableViewController`s

Now when the user is, say, in A3, they can press another `TabBar` item and jump to another hierarchy (say, the one of B). However, when they press the item for A, they will jump back to A3.

What I do want to happen, is for them to jump to A1 instead, which is essentially the "parent" `UIView` in the A hierarchy. Similarly, if they press B, they should jump to B1, not to wherever they were in the B hierarchy. I do **not** want to force the user to go back to e.g. A1 manually by hiding the bottom bar (the one from the `TabBarController`).

What is the best way to achieve this?

For visualisation:

```
    /- A - A1 - A2 - A3
X ---- B - B1 - ...
    \- C - ...
```

Programmatically, I currently have custom classes for X (`TabBarController, TabBarControllerDelegate`) and the `TableViewController`s A1,...,B1,... . When the user presses an item, I can by debugging see that the target VC for the segue would be A/B/... and not A1/B1/... so I cannot control the process this way.

EDIT: check storyboard image below.

[image]

Comment: "For tab bars with an associated tab bar controller, the tab bar controller automatically manages selections and displays the appropriate view controller. The only time you have to manage selections yourself is when you create the tab bar without a tab bar controller." Taken from docs. In other words, the behavior you are seeking is the default behavior when set up properly.

Comment: @CSmizzle As I wrote, the TBC jumps to the appropriate one of the NavigationControllers (A/B/C). At least that is what I see when I print the VC the segue points to. However, after that it somehow gets forwarded to e.g. A3 since the user was last in A3 on the A branch. What I want is to always go to A1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but the bottomline is whenever the user taps on the tab bar you want the user to be able to see the root controller of each of the `UINavigationController`, correct?

You mentioned that you already have a custom `TabBarController` so have you tried the `shouldSelect` method?:

```swift
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        (viewController as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        return true
    }
}
```

This seems to be working when I tried it on my playground.

Here's the full code I tried it with:

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class A: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "A"
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .init(x: 100, y: 100), size: .init(width: 200, height: 100)))
        label.text = "A"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .init(x: 100, y: 200), size: .init(width: 200, height: 100)))
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let a1 = A1()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(a1, animated: true)
    }
}

class A1: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .init(x: 100, y: 100), size: .init(width: 200, height: 100)))
        label.text = "A1"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        
    }
}

class B: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "B"
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .init(x: 100, y: 100), size: .init(width: 200, height: 100)))
        label.text = "B"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .init(x: 100, y: 200), size: .init(width: 200, height: 100)))
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let b1 = B1()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(b1, animated: true)
    }
}

class B1: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .init(x: 100, y: 100), size: .init(width: 200, height: 100)))
        label.text = "B1"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }

}

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        (viewController as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        return true
    }
}

let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: A())
let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: B())

let tabbarVC = CustomTabBarController()
tabbarVC.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
tabbarVC.addChild(nav1)
tabbarVC.addChild(nav2)

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = tabbarVC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So "I'm not sure if I understood you correctly..." -> you did, yes. I had also tried the `shouldSelect` method but its argument was the NavController and I didn't know what to do with it since I wanted to land on the first TableViewController. What from your answer really did help me was the `popToRootViewController ` method and the row with it.